# SwiftでCoreDataのユニットテスト時にEXC_BREAKPOINTエラーが発生します

Tags: ios, swift

タイトルの事象が発生します。以下を読むとよくある問題みたいですが、試しても解決しませんでした。
同じ現象が発生して、解決できた方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授お願いします。

[SwiftでNSManagedObjectのSubclassを使った上でテストも書きたい！書けます！](http://qiita.com/YukiAsu/items/74eb1d1a5687e870d1ae)

本家にも質問投稿しました。

Swift CoreData UnitTest: How to avoid EXC_BREAKPOINT
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313645/swift-coredata-unittest-how-to-avoid-exc-breakpoint